# LookupError: App 'users' doesn't have a 'user' model

Tags: django

Django 1.9.7
I'm using pyenv virtualenv autoenv

I want to extend user model so, i decide to use `AbstractUser`

(AbstractUser's `class META` abstract = True, so i can't make table, but inheritance class can make table, right??)

anyways

(wef is project name)
I make app `wef/users/models/__init__.py`

```
from .user import User
```

In `wef/users/models/user.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):

    phonenumber = models.CharField(
            max_length = 11,
            blank = True,
            null = True
            )
```

and I add `users`app in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    [...]
    'users',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

So, I think when i makemigrations, migrate

django will make model table about User...

`python wef/manage.py makemigrations users`

it shows error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 163, in get_model
return self.models[model_name.lower()]
KeyError: 'user'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
self.check()
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/checks.py", line 12, in check_user_model
cls = apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 197, in get_model
return self.get_app_config(app_label).get_model(model_name.lower())
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 166, in get_model
"App '%s' doesn't have a '%s' model." % (self.label, model_name))
LookupError: App 'users' doesn't have a 'user' model.
```

I can't understand why django can't found users.User model

and when I change `AUTH_USER_MODEL=UserAAA'

it show error (capital letters is changed lower case)

`LookupError: App 'users' doesn't have a 'useraaa' model.`

I can not find my problem
please somebody help me.. ㅠ_ㅠ

Comment: Is your package really "modes", rather than "models"?

Comment: oh sorry edit my mistake but it has same error

Comment: please somebody help me I'm really needs anyone's help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have already created your database schema. From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/):

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL has a big effect on your database structure.
>   It changes the tables that are available, and it will affect the
>   construction of foreign keys and many-to-many relationships. If you
>   intend to set AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should set it before creating any
>   migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time.
>
> Changing this setting after you have tables created is not supported
>   by makemigrations and will result in you having to manually fix your
>   schema, port your data from the old user table, and possibly manually
>   reapply some migrations.

Comment: thank you @Gupta i'll try delete db.sqlite3 and `manage.py reset_db`

Comment: I have the same issue, but I've always used this custom User model. I just moved from `models.py` to `models/__init__.py` What could be the issue in that case?

Comment: So I can answer my own question, my `__init__.py` needed to `from .user import User` before importing any other models that called `get_user_model()`

Comment: This was also the case for me, I'm quite happy I read through the comments, thanks :). Also, I guess you could consider adding this as an answer, @AaronMcMillin

Comment: @AaronMcMillin this is the solution, but I can't explain why! This deserves an explanation, since it sounds like a workaround to a bug. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I have a couple more options to resolve this.

1. If you really want to migrate from the the contrib.auth

Put `db_table = 'auth_user'` in your model's Meta to use the existing table and not break the other relations. Make a migration without any custom fields, then make your model changes and another migration.

2. I moved my models.py to models/__init__.py

In that case I needed to have `from .user import User` before importing any other models that called `get_user_model()`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and it was resolved after I deleted this line

```
from .user import User
```

Also, delete all the 'User' imports in your project after you created a custom user model