# Django not discovering models when moved into folder

Tags: python, django

My previous layout:

```
project:
    app:
        models.py
```

Right now it is like this:

```
project:
    app:
        models:
            __init__.py
            model_name.py
```

Because I have many more models now so I had to separate them.
Inside `project/app/models/__init__.py` I have imported the model, hence I can import from `app.models` instead of `app.models.model_name`, but I'm getting `ImproperlyConfigured`.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.User' that has not been installed
```

settings.py:

```
APPS = [
    'comments',
    'forums',
    'notifications',
    'posts',
    'privatemessages',
    'profiles',
    'subforums',
    'summaryreports',
    'users',
]
```

Users app layout:

[image]

users.models.init.py:

```
from users.models.user_backends import UserBackend
from users.models.users import User
```

users.apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'
```

Why???

**EDIT:**

In settings.py, also tried:

```
APPS = [
    'comments.apps.CommentsConfig',
    'forums.apps.ForumsConfig',
    'notifications.apps.NotificationsConfig',
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
    'privatemessages.apps.PrivateMessagesConfig',
    'profiles.apps.ProfilesConfig',
    'subforums.apps.SubforumsConfig',
    'summaryreports.apps.SummaryreportsConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]
```

Django version is 3.1. Python 3.8.5.
WSGI and ASGI are properly pointing to settings.py.

**EDIT 2:** [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded):

*Then Django attempts to import the models submodule of each application, if there is one.
You must define or import all models in your application’s models.py or models/**init**.py. Otherwise, the application registry may not be fully populated at this point, which could cause the ORM to malfunction.*

**EDIT 3*: Full stack trace:

```
django_1        | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
django_1        | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
django_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 178, in get_model
django_1        |     return self.models[model_name.lower()]
django_1        | KeyError: 'user'
django_1        | 
django_1        | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django_1        | 
django_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 157, in get_user_model
django_1        |     return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 210, in get_model
django_1        |     return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 180, in get_model
django_1        |     raise LookupError(
django_1        | LookupError: App 'users' doesn't have a 'User' model.
django_1        | 
django_1        | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django_1        | 
django_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
django_1        |     self.run()
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
django_1        |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
django_1        |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
django_1        |     autoreload.raise_last_exception()
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
django_1        |     raise _exception[1]
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
django_1        |     autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
django_1        |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
django_1        |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
django_1        |     app_config.import_models()
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
django_1        |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
django_1        |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django_1        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
django_1        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
django_1        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django_1        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
django_1        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
django_1        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
django_1        |   File "/app/comments/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
django_1        |     from comments.models.comments import Comment
django_1        |   File "/app/comments/models/comments.py", line 7, in <module>
django_1        |     from users.models import User
django_1        |   File "/app/users/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
django_1        |     from users.models.user_backends import UserBackend
django_1        |   File "/app/users/models/user_backends.py", line 8, in <module>
django_1        |     from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 5, in <module>
django_1        |     UserModel = get_user_model()
django_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 161, in get_user_model
django_1        |     raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django_1        | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.User' that has not been installed
```

Comment: Post the full traceback. Let's see which which code is raising this exception.

Comment: @xyres done! It's posted.

Comment: This error message seems very much like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38630321/1925257.

Comment: @xyres Hmmm I used this User model from the beginning of the project. The only thing I did was moving the modules into a models folder. Anyway I nuked the database and reset migrations, but the error persisted.